# How to route to a page inside a function in React w/ React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a form in my react app that I made w/ bootstrap and react-router. When the user hits submit, I want them to go to a page, if the credentials are correct, else do nothing.

```
<button
  class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold"
  type="submit"
  onClick={handleSubmit}
>
Submit</button>
```

...

```
function handleSubmit() {
  if (credentials.are.correct) {
    // go to page here
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do the above in react-router, without installing any third-party software?

Comment: Are you just asking how to redirect to other page with react-router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're all set and have you app wrapped in Router provider you can `useHistory` hook. Here's an example from [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) docs:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) you can read how you can use `history.push("route")` method to use it in your code. So you just check if credentials are fine and if yes you just do `history.push` to a route that you want.

Answer (score 0):

react-router has very nice documentation on this subject :)

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

just do it like this if you are using hooks

```
function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works like a charm. But since I got a lot of replies all saying the same, I'll be picking up the most comprehensive one :)